# PhantomJS not accepting Cross Domain Cookies

Tags: javascript, node.js, cookies

Hey guys i am using PhantomJS (1.10.0) and Node-phantom-simple (https://github.com/baudehlo/node-phantom-simple) in order to control phantom through a node script. There seems to be an issue when trying to add/set cookies in phantom for a domain other than the one phantom is currently on. It seems that phantom simple ignores the cross domain cookies and doesnt add them. Has anyone else experience this problem/ have any ideas of how to fix it?

**Cookie To Add**
"test_cookie=CheckForPermission; path=/; domain=.doubleclick.net;"

**What I Have Tried:**
I first tried using phantoms add and set cookie methods to add the cross domain cookie but phantom did not add the cookie. I then tried using the injectJs method to inject a javascript file with the bellow contents

```
document.cookie = "test_cookie=CheckForPermission; path=/; domain=.doubleclick.net;";
```

but phantom still did not add the cookie to its cookie jar. However if i remove the domain part of the above statement the cookie is added with domain equal to phantoms current domain. How can i fix this and have the domain be set to ".doubleclick.net"

Comment: Why don't you use [API](http://phantomjs.org/api/phantom/method/add-cookie.html)?

Comment: As i said in the post i tried using the api but the cross domain cookies are not accepted

Comment: did you find answer? Please share your solution